# PHP Help explaining a Function

Tags: php, sql

```
 function sql_like_expression($expression)
 {
     $expression = utf8_str_replace(array('_', '%'), array("\_", "\%"), $expression);
     $expression = utf8_str_replace(array(chr(0) . "\_", chr(0) . "\%"), array('_', '%'), $expression);

     return $this->_sql_like_expression('LIKE \'' . $this->sql_escape($expression) . '\'');
 }
```

I am not sure what this function is doing. From what I am seeing, i think it replaces `_` with `\_` though I am unsure if thats exactly whats going on. Why is it `array`'s and what do the `%` mean?
Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a SQL LIKE expression, the `_` means *any single character*, and `%` means *any characters*.

- The first line *escapes* the `%` and `_` characters to remove their special meaning (adding a `\` before them removes their special meaning)
- The second line unescapes the `%` and `_` characters that was preceeded by a NULL byte (char(0)).

The use of arrays in str_replace allows to do multiple replacements at once.

Answer (score 2):

% and _ are used in SQL like statements, they are wildcards.  % matches any set of characters, while _ matches a single character.

Having \% means it will NOT match any characters, it escapes it so it is now a literal, likewise for the _.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very corny and unreliable method of doing SQL escaping. Find whoever wrote that and slap them around with a stinky slimy fish for a few hours.

In short, it's doing a 1:1 replacement of the two arrays:

```
_ -> \_
% => \%
```

and then the same with string where there's (for some reason) a NULL char before the original string's critical values.

Comment: You should probably explain to the class why it's corny/unreliable.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Helped me out alot. i agree with webbiedave though

Comment: It doesn't escapes the `\ ` character. `"foo \%"` becomes `"foo \\%"` when `%` is replaced by `\%s`. As a result the `%` is effectively not escaped. Also, it assumes that the string can't contain malicious NULLs.

Comment: I was merely suggesting that Marc B place that in his answer.